# Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest

Making a RestTemplate project.

```
Invoke ResponseEntity<List> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                requestEntity,
                List.class)
```

my baseUrl is "http://94.198.50.185:7081/api/users",
I get an error:  Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: http://94.198.50.185:7081/api/users

```
What's this? ))
```

https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.5.git

Answer (score 0):

All is working, just be more attentive